# MacOS -bash:Command not found

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, environment-variables, d2rq

when I try to use the command `d2r-server.bat kg_demo_movie_mapping.ttl` in the terminal, the command not found.

[image]
And I tried to modify the `.bash_profile` as follow :

[image]

it's still not working.

Is there anyway to fix this?

The picture of bat file, and the terminal :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is `d2r-server.bat`? If it's in the current directory (under Downloads perhaps?), you'll need to tell bash to look there by prefixing your script name with ".\". You'd call the script using  `.\d2r-server.bat kg_demo_movie_mapping.ttl`. (Note that a _.bat_ file usually indicates a Windows script and not something your can run on MacOS.)

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I have fixed the problem. But I still cannot run the command... It seems like the bat file exist some syntax errors. but when the file was run on the windows, it worked well.  But I just download the folder from d2rq website, so how can I run a .bat on MacOS? I have tried to change the .bat to .sh, the syntax error still exist.

Comment: A windows batch file likely won’t run in MacOS at all. You will need to find a Mac version of the software you are using.

Comment: But there is no Mac version of d2rq, it's actually a folder I downloaded from http://d2rq.org/.

Comment: Took a  quick glance at the project. Looks like the bash equivalents for the batch files are included (same name, but no .bat extension).

Comment: So does it mean I can run the command on the terminal?  But there still exist some syntax errors. I am not familiar with the syntax of bat file, so I really don't know how to deal with it... Please check the picture in my answer.

Comment: You won't run the batch files on your Mac at all. There are other scripts for bash. Look through the files and you'll see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch files are for Windows use. In a bash shell you'll need a bash script. Bash scripts can be identified by a shebang line at the top of the script, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

In the specific case of the *d2rq* package there are scripts included. Look through the files in your downloaded package and you'll find the bash scripts share the same basename without the `.bat` extension of the windows batch files.